# Terminology for when any node in a network can claim the coordinator role?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

I currently have a product that works in a simple master/slave(s) setup.  The master coordinates communication between itself and all slave nodes (and between slave nodes).  Now I want to modify this product so that any node can assume the coordinator role (so that master/slave designations are no longer static).

Is there an existing term for this sort of setup?  I can think of a couple options but I don't want to bias the answers.

(And for those questioning why I'd ask this on StackOverflow, I think choosing the correct terminology for your design and functionality is an extremely important programming practice.  After all, there's a lot more to programming than knowing where to put the semi-colon.  Please consider this before you automatically close the question as off-topic.)

Edit:  For clarification, only one node at a time can assume the coordinator role.  So while any node can take on the role, there can not be multiples at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multi master, peer to peer, without single point of failure, leader election, decentralized